# Onclick event not happening when slick slider is active and not adapting responsively

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a tabbed style module in which the "triggers" turn into a `slick slider` depending on width.

- If width is less than `576px`, `slick` is active showing 2 slides initially.
- If width is more than `576px` and less than `768px`, `slick` is active showing 3 slides initially.
- If width is more than `768px` and less than `1024px`, `slick` is active showing 4 slides initially.
- If width is more than `1400px`, `slick` is not active.

When you click on a "trigger" (`.caseStudyTrigger`), content changes based on trigger choice, which currently kind of works.

**Issues:**

The issue is that, whenever slick is active, the `onclick` event on `.caseStudyTrigger` doesn't work. I have tried `console.log("test");` within the `click function` and even that doesn't appear.

Additionally, I have a `resize` function so that `slick` can adapt to 2,3 4 slides based on the device width. However, when resizing, I always have to refresh the page on that width for slick to show the correct number of slides?

**Demo:**

```js
$(function() {


  $(".caseStudies .caseStudyTrigger:first-child").addClass("activeTrigger");
  $(".caseStudies .caseStudyCard:first-child").addClass("activeCard");

  $('.caseStudies .caseStudyTrigger').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-trigger');

    $(".caseStudies .caseStudyTrigger").removeClass("activeTrigger");
    $(this).addClass("activeTrigger");

    $(".caseStudies .caseStudyCard").removeClass("activeCard");
    $(".caseStudies .caseStudyCard[data-item='" + id + "']").addClass("activeCard");
  });


  function caseStudies__slick() {
    $("#caseStudies__slick").slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
      mobileFirst: true,
      infinite: true,
      centerMode: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 576,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 1400,
          settings: 'unslick'
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  var $window_width = $(window).width();

  if ($window_width < 1400) {
    caseStudies__slick();
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($window_width < 1400) {
      $("#caseStudies__slick").slick("resize");
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.caseStudies .slick-list {
  padding: 0px 20% !important;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .caseStudies .slick-list {
    paddding: 0 !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies__triggers {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}

.caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger {
  max-width: 305px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 68px 25px 80px 25px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger {
    padding: 100px 25px 80px 25px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger {
    padding: 125px 75px;
  }
}

.caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger.activeTrigger {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies__body {
    padding-bottom: 125px;
  }
}

.caseStudies .caseStudyCard {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies .caseStudyCard {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.caseStudies .caseStudyCard.activeCard {
  display: flex;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" />

<div class="caseStudies">

  <!-- TRIGGERS -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 px-0 px-md-auto">
        <div class="caseStudies__triggers" id="caseStudies__slick">

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="1">
            Trigger 1
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="2">
            Trigger 2
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="3">
            Trigger 3
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="4">
            Trigger 4
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="5">
            Trigger 5
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="6">
            Trigger 6
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- CONTENT BASED ON TRIGGER SELECTED -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 px-0 px-md-auto">
        <div class="caseStudies__body">

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="1">
            Content for trigger 1
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="2">
            Content for trigger 2
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="3">
            Content for trigger 3
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="4">
            Content for trigger 4
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="5">
            Content for trigger 5
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="6">
            Content for trigger 6
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** I couldn't reproduce your click handler issue - it works also in your stack snippet. Therefor i presume that it's something that you didn't post in your question, or you have other classes in your original code etc..

---

### **I found two issues:**

- You declare at page load a variable `$window_width`, which will never change. Even on `resize` it will remain like declared. Therefor you have to get `$(window).width()` again when the `resize` handler is called:

```js
if ($(window).width() < 1400) {
```

- In your `click` handler you apply the class `.activeTrigger` only to the clicked element. But `slick` clones elements, for example for the infinite scroll, and sometimes centeres the clone and not the click-target. Therefor you should apply the class to all elements with the id-value like you do with the content cards:

```js
$(".caseStudies .caseStudyTrigger[data-trigger='" + id + "']").addClass("activeTrigger");
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(function() {


  $(".caseStudies .caseStudyTrigger:first-child").addClass("activeTrigger");
  $(".caseStudies .caseStudyCard:first-child").addClass("activeCard");

  $('.caseStudies .caseStudyTrigger').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-trigger');

    $(".caseStudies .caseStudyTrigger").removeClass("activeTrigger");
    $(".caseStudies .caseStudyTrigger[data-trigger='" + id + "']").addClass("activeTrigger");

    $(".caseStudies .caseStudyCard").removeClass("activeCard");
    $(".caseStudies .caseStudyCard[data-item='" + id + "']").addClass("activeCard");
  });


  function caseStudies__slick() {
    $("#caseStudies__slick").not('.slick-initialized').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
      mobileFirst: true,
      infinite: true,
      centerMode: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 576,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 1400,
          settings: 'unslick'
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  var $window_width = $(window).width();

  if ($window_width < 1400) {
    caseStudies__slick();
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1400) {
      $("#caseStudies__slick").slick("resize");
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.caseStudies .slick-list {
  padding: 0px 20% !important;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .caseStudies .slick-list {
    paddding: 0 !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies__triggers {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}

.caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger {
  max-width: 305px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 68px 25px 80px 25px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger {
    padding: 100px 25px 80px 25px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger {
    padding: 125px 75px;
  }
}

.caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger.activeTrigger {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies__body {
    padding-bottom: 125px;
  }
}

.caseStudies .caseStudyCard {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies .caseStudyCard {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.caseStudies .caseStudyCard.activeCard {
  display: flex;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" />

<div class="caseStudies">

  <!-- TRIGGERS -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 px-0 px-md-auto">
        <div class="caseStudies__triggers" id="caseStudies__slick">

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="1">
            Trigger 1
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="2">
            Trigger 2
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="3">
            Trigger 3
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="4">
            Trigger 4
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="5">
            Trigger 5
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="6">
            Trigger 6
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- CONTENT BASED ON TRIGGER SELECTED -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 px-0 px-md-auto">
        <div class="caseStudies__body">

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="1">
            Content for trigger 1
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="2">
            Content for trigger 2
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="3">
            Content for trigger 3
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="4">
            Content for trigger 4
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="5">
            Content for trigger 5
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="6">
            Content for trigger 6
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

---

### **Optimization:**

- Since you handle the case for window width greater than 1400px in your slick settings (`responsive:`) there is no need for the if statement `if ($(window).width() < 1400)`. Therefor you can omit it on resize and at initial call of the function `caseStudies__slick()`:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  $("#caseStudies__slick").slick('resize');
});

caseStudies__slick();
```

- Since you call the function `caseStudies__slick()` only once at page load there is no need for that function and the slick slider can be declared directly, which makes the initial function call unnecessary.
- Since there are only `.caseStudyTrigger`- and `.caseStudyCard`-elements in the container `.caseStudies` there is no need to add the container class to the selector. It improves the readbility to omit this class. For example:

```js
$(".caseStudyTrigger").removeClass("activeTrigger");
```

- Also for readability i would put the event listeners at the end of the script.

**Working example:**

```js
$(function(){

  
  $(".caseStudyTrigger:first-child").addClass("activeTrigger");
  $(".caseStudyCard:first-child").addClass("activeCard");

  $("#caseStudies__slick").not('.slick-initialized').slick({
  
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    mobileFirst: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 576,
        settings : {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings : {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings : {
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 2,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 1400,
        settings: 'unslick'
      }
    ]
    
  });

  $('.caseStudyTrigger').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-trigger');

    $(".caseStudyTrigger").removeClass("activeTrigger");
    $(".caseStudyTrigger[data-trigger='" + id + "']").addClass("activeTrigger");

    $(".caseStudyCard").removeClass("activeCard");
    $(".caseStudyCard[data-item='"+id+"']").addClass("activeCard");
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    $("#caseStudies__slick").slick('resize');
  });


});
```

```css
.caseStudies .slick-list {
  padding: 0px 20% !important;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .caseStudies .slick-list {
    paddding: 0 !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies__triggers {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}

.caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger {
  max-width: 305px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 68px 25px 80px 25px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger {
    padding: 100px 25px 80px 25px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger {
    padding: 125px 75px;
  }
}

.caseStudies__triggers .caseStudyTrigger.activeTrigger {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies__body {
    padding-bottom: 125px;
  }
}

.caseStudies .caseStudyCard {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .caseStudies .caseStudyCard {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.caseStudies .caseStudyCard.activeCard {
  display: flex;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" />

<div class="caseStudies">

  <!-- TRIGGERS -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 px-0 px-md-auto">
        <div class="caseStudies__triggers" id="caseStudies__slick">

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="1">
            Trigger 1
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="2">
            Trigger 2
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="3">
            Trigger 3
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="4">
            Trigger 4
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="5">
            Trigger 5
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyTrigger" data-trigger="6">
            Trigger 6
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- CONTENT BASED ON TRIGGER SELECTED -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 px-0 px-md-auto">
        <div class="caseStudies__body">

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="1">
            Content for trigger 1
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="2">
            Content for trigger 2
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="3">
            Content for trigger 3
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="4">
            Content for trigger 4
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="5">
            Content for trigger 5
          </div>

          <div class="caseStudyCard" data-item="6">
            Content for trigger 6
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Much appreciated and grateful for the in-depth walkthrough :) Can confirm your suggestions fixed the issues